# CSS: top percentage doesn't work on all browsers

Tags: css, android-browser

I'm aiming to position an image to the middle inside a div. It works great, but for some reason, `top` doesn't have any effect on the Android browser.

Very likely, I have my divs set incorrectly where the img one cannot determine it's container height (so percentage makes no sense...).

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hL56gqsd/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Comment: I'll bounty this with 50 points when eligible given that I've spent all day figuring it out without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your parent `.container` as `relative` and your child `.container img` as `absolute`

This was tested in Android 5.1.1 using Firefox.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**

> **Absolute positioning**
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor(non
>   static). If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container
>   is used

#### Snippet

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.container img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [trick](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VsakD/8/)

```css
.parentbox {
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    border-style:solid;
    
    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

.parentbox:before {      /* create a full-height inline block pseudo-element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

.childbox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;          /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    font: 16px/1 Arial, sans-serif;  /* reset the font property */
    
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentbox">
    <div class="childbox">
        I shall be in the middle of parentbox regardless of its size!
    </div>
</div>
```